# ¿Como puedo especificar una variable sin tener en cuenta el orden?

Tags: javascript

Por ejemplo yo deseo solo pasar un valor a la función y que los demás sean valores por defecto de la función:

```
const saludar = function(nombre='Visitante', edad=20, profesion='Desarrollador Web'){
    return `Tienes ${edad}, eres ${profesion} y te llamas ${nombre}`;
}

console.log(saludar(edad=35));
```

Y quiero solo darle la variable `edad=35` , entonces quiero que imprima:

```
Tienes 35, eres Desarrollador Web y te llamas Visitante
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

usando [asignación de desestructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment#Argumentos_por_defecto_en_funciones)

```js
const saludar = function({
  nombre = 'Visitante',
  edad = 20,
  profesion = 'Desarrollador Web'
} = {}) {
  return `Tienes ${edad}, eres ${profesion} y te llamas ${nombre}`;
}

console.log(saludar({
  edad: 35
}));

console.log(saludar({
  nombre: 'Felix'
}));

// variante cuando la variable con el valor 
// tiene el mismo nombre que el parámetro

let profesion = 'Tsunami Surfer';
console.log(
  saludar({
    profesion
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa solo tu parámetro que es variable y declara las constantes dentro de la funcion.
ejemplo:

```
const saludar = function(nombre){
   return "Hola" + nombre + " tu edad es 35 y eres Desarrollador WEB"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Elimina los parámetros iniciales que tienes en tu declaración de la función
- Pasa estos al interior del cuerpo de la función
- Cuando invocas a la función solo pasa el valor que espera la variable y no de nuevo la declaración de la variable y la asignación del valor
- De modo que sea ese el único valor esperado y los demás los tome de las variables internas de la función
- Con lo anterior evitarás que lea la edad del argumento como valor de la variable nombre
- Entonces originalmente edad valdrá 20 pero cuando invocas a la función pasando el argumento de 35 este anula al anterior

Código

```js
    const saludar = function(edad=20){
        nombre='Visitante'
        profesion='Desarrollador Web'
        return `Tienes ${edad}, eres ${profesion} y te llamas ${nombre}`;
    }
    
    console.log(saludar(35));
```